# What does <bdi> do?

Tags: html

I'm aware that its for text that runs in the opposite direction of the rest of the page, but I'm not fully understanding what it does. Does it just mark it so the browser knows its running in the opposite direction? If so why does the browser benefit from knowing this? Also what is the "surrounding text", is it literally just the text around it, its getting compared to or is it getting compared to the lang attribute?

```
<p>this is text going from left to right <bdi>opposite running text</bdi></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The BDI tag(bidirectional isolation) isolates a span of text that might be formatted in a different direction from other text outside it.

This resource has some data for you to read.

http://html.com/tags/bdi/